# AngularJS : How can I avoid tightly coupling stacked directives when both need values from parent scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to wrap a 3rd party (non-Angular) library in a set of Angular directives for use in my application. So far I've got a base control that I wrapped in a directive (basically on link it just replaces a div in the template with the 3rd party control). I wanted to setup this directive to be re-used across my app as I'll need the control multiple times. This seemed to call for an Isolate scope and to setup bindings on my views to avoid tight coupling. This works for the base functionality, but in some cases I need to extend the functionality of that control.

My thought was to create a second directive that leveraged different parts of the 3rd party library to add functionality to the base control. This directive would need to communicate with the 3rd party control in the first directive, as well as bind to values on the parent view. I setup both directives as `restrict: 'A'` to make them attributes, then I stack them on a single div in my view -

```
<div directive-base directive-add-on />
```

The problem here is communicating between all the different pieces. If the base directive is an isolate scope, the add-on can't be isolate and thus can't communicate with the parent view. If I make them both child scope I can see everything on the parent scope, but then I'm more tightly coupling my directives to my view's controller.

Is there a different approach to doing this that avoids the tight coupling?

Answer (score 0):

Can you treat the add-ons as attribute arguments to the directive-base?

Normally, I'd have a directive on an element like:

```
<directive-base add-on="true_or_scope_variable"></directive-base>
```

In your directive link function or associated controller, you can adjust the content based on the attribute values.

Does this work?

Comment: Good point, and I thought about that. The reason I didn't go that route was because I actually want to re-use the base directive in several apps and the add-ons will contain app specific code. I thought maybe I could avoid app specific code in the add-ons, but in order to do that in this case I'd have to expose my 3rd party objects to the parent view/controller and interact with them (sometimes resulting in DOM manipulation in the 3rd party library). Trying to be a good Angular citizen, I was trying to avoid that problem as well.

Comment: Communication between directives is hard; I can't say I've ever gotten it to work.

Can you have two simple directives (base and add-on), but wrap them in a simple parent directive+controller that handles communication?